# How to set password for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, passwords, xampp

Installing XAMPP will set password for MySQL as blank as default.

Going for `password` in `my.ini` file doesn't work.

How can we set password for it?

Comment: My I suggest that you take a short look into the excellent mysql documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change the password through the webinterface, try going to: `http://localhost/security/`, another way would be to run the following query from mysql:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may help you with your issue and offers 2 methods.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/

Comment: Please make a copy of the link in your answer in case the link dies.